# meaning of "race into lead"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, usage

I'm a little bit confused by the construction "race into lead" here. The verb "race" means to move at speed". So I understand it as "to move at speed into lead. Could you tell me how you rephrase it?

> ⏱️ Half Time | Latics 1-2 Burnley

> Burnley **raced into** a two-goal **lead** through efforts from Jay
> Rodriguez and Josh Brownhill, but Will Keane's  penalty has Latics
> right back in it at the DW!
>
> #wafc ⚪️ #BELIEVE

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common metaphor.

In a race, the *lead* would be a position, a physical configuration, and you could move in and out of it.

In a game it is not a physical position, but metaphorically it can be regarded the same way, so you can *race into the lead*, you can *drop behind*, you can *lag*.,and a host of other positional metaphors.

Comment: Why does the writer use "race" instead of "take?" Usually the phrase is "take the lead" as I know.

Comment: This question has already been answered for you!! It simply means _took the lead very quickly_.

Comment: _Take the lead_ does not use the positional metaphor, which is about _moving_ into the lead. _Race_ into the lead is a dynamic kind of epxression that sports writers are fond of.

Answer (score 0):

"Lead" in this context means "number of goals ahead."

The suggestion is that this happened early in the game.

> Early in the game, Burnley got ahead by two goals, but ...

Comment: why does the writer use "race" instead of "take?" Usually the phrase is "take the lead" as I know.

Comment: @Jembot Burnley "raced" (moved quickly) into the lead. It an emphasizes how quickly he took the lead.